# Can my Ethereum Based Tokens / Coins be traded on a crypto currency exchange?

Tags: wallets, tokens, exchanges, erc-20

I am building my own Crypto based on Ethereum Blockchain. Is it possible for this newly created currency to be traded on any crypto currency exchange?

And secondly, will my new currency be compatible with any normal Ethereum Wallet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ERC-20 tokens can be listed on various exchanges and they already do.

They need to be explicitly listed and some exchanges will ask money upfront.

At the moment, wallets maintain internal list of token names and contract addresses, and each wallet must be updated separately to display your token.

Comment: Ok excellent thanks. And is it complicated to list them with exchanges ? I mean, is there any coding manipulation to do or things like that ? 

Ok got it for Walllet issue. How may I clear this problem? Since it will be listed on exchanges with millions of people holding the coins, it will be like hell to explain to all those people how to enable my coin in their wallet. Any suggestion ?

Comment: You contact the wallet developers and they will push a wallet update that lists your token.

Comment: In some wallets like Mist and Parity, users can also register the ERC20 compatible tokens by putting the address of token contract.